# In Leaflet, how to convert leaflet viewport bounding box in EPSG3857 so I can retrieve data stored in EPSG4326

Tags: leaflet, gis

My government supplied mapping data is stored in our database with projection EPSG4326. Because all the data is stored as longitudes and latitudes, this data can be loaded and displayed in leaflet successfully and correctly, even though leaflet itself is defaulted to projection EPSG3857. It's ok to do that, as there is no point switching leaflet over to EPSG4326 as there are no map providers that provide map tiles that are projected for EPSG4326 and I don't want to generate them myself.

There is a lot of data, so I only want to retrieve the data that is within the visible viewport. Leaflet provides me with the getBounds() method to retrieve the longitude and latitude of the visible viewport. Unfortunately, the coordinates it provides me are EPSG3857 coordinates, which means that the data retrieved is distorted around the borders - the difference between 4326 and 3857 means that the curve is wrong.

In the image below, I have passed the longitude and latitude of the bounding box to the database and intersected it with the data. I have drawn the green line to show the problem with using the EPSG3857 coordinates that leaflet has provided me. If the coordinates were EPSG4326, then it would have given me wider coordinates that would have retrieved the data above the green line and within the viewport.

I've currently got a hack where I add a couple of degrees to the longitude and latitude of the bounding box, but I was hoping a better solution exists. Is there a better way to achieve this? Can I somehow translate the bounding box to EPSG4326 without having to switch the whole thing over to EPSG4326, thereby losing the map tiles?

[image: Distortion Image]

**Update:**

Here is the code I am using in SQL Server on the back end:

```
CREATE PROC [core].[GetGeoData]
    @Zoom int,
    @BoundingBox_N decimal(18,14),
    @BoundingBox_S decimal(18,14),
    @BoundingBox_E decimal(18,14),
    @BoundingBox_W decimal(18,14)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @BoundingBox varchar(200)
    DECLARE @BoundingBoxGeo geography
    SET @BoundingBox = 'POLYGON((' + CAST(@BoundingBox_E as varchar(20)) + ' ' + CAST(@BoundingBox_S as varchar(20)) + ',' + CAST(@BoundingBox_E as varchar(20)) + ' ' + CAST(@BoundingBox_N as varchar(20)) + ',' + CAST(@BoundingBox_W as varchar(20)) + ' ' + CAST(@BoundingBox_N as varchar(20)) + ',' + CAST(@BoundingBox_W as varchar(20)) + ' ' + CAST(@BoundingBox_S as varchar(20)) + ',' + CAST(@BoundingBox_E as varchar(20)) + ' ' + CAST(@BoundingBox_S as varchar(20)) + '))'
    SET @BoundingBoxGeo = geography::STGeomFromText(@BoundingBox, 4326)

    SELECT PostalCode, geo.STIntersection(@BoundingBoxGeo) AS geo
    FROM [geo].[AustralianGeoData]  
    WHERE  zoom=@Zoom AND geo.STIntersects(@BoundingBoxGeo)=1

END
```

On the front end, inside my code I am calling:

```
const mapBounds = map.getBounds();
const zoom = this.map.getZoom();
const boundingBoxN = mapBounds.getNorth();
const boundingBoxS = mapBounds.getSouth();
const boundingBoxE = mapBounds.getEast();
const boundingBoxW = mapBounds.getWest();
this.mapService.getGeoData(zoom, boundingBoxN, boundingBoxS, boundingBoxE, boundingBoxW)
            .subscribe(
            response => { 
   const geoJson = JSON.parse(row.geoJson);
   this.layers.push(geoJson);
});
```

which passes the bounding box directly to the back end. map is an L.map instance.

Comment: You should provide the code that reproduces your issue.

Comment: OP is wrong - The CRS of `map.getBounds()` is in EPSG:4326 even if the display projection is EPSG:3857. Furthermore, lines of parallel are not distorted between 4326 and 3857. I must suspect that there the backend is taking in 4326, reprojecting to something like an UTM band (which would distort parallels), then making the query based on a naïve reprojection of the bbox's corners.

Comment: Extra info provided above. I would be happy if I had a calculation for the distance between the line at the midway point and the top of the viewport. Then I could just add that distance to the latitude and be done with it!

Comment: I just switched the map over to EPSG4236 in leaflet, and above the curve is still being truncated. Therefore it must be the way the intersection is being done - perhaps it's doing some sort of geometry intersection instead of geography intersection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have changed the query to use geometry types instead of geography types when performing the intersection. This retrieves exactly the right data - when I move the map around I can see that data was loaded only in the viewport, as there is a small delay while the unloaded region is retrieved and the new layer rendered.

My stored procedure now looks like this:

```
ALTER PROC [core].[GetGeoData]
    @Zoom int,
    @BoundingBox_N decimal(18,14),
    @BoundingBox_S decimal(18,14),
    @BoundingBox_E decimal(18,14),
    @BoundingBox_W decimal(18,14)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @BoundingBox varchar(200)
    DECLARE @BoundingBoxGeo geometry
    SET @BoundingBox = 'POLYGON((' + CAST(@BoundingBox_E as varchar(20)) + ' ' + CAST(@BoundingBox_S as varchar(20)) + ',' + CAST(@BoundingBox_E as varchar(20)) + ' ' + CAST(@BoundingBox_N as varchar(20)) + ',' + CAST(@BoundingBox_W as varchar(20)) + ' ' + CAST(@BoundingBox_N as varchar(20)) + ',' + CAST(@BoundingBox_W as varchar(20)) + ' ' + CAST(@BoundingBox_S as varchar(20)) + ',' + CAST(@BoundingBox_E as varchar(20)) + ' ' + CAST(@BoundingBox_S as varchar(20)) + '))'
    SET @BoundingBoxGeo = geometry::STGeomFromText(@BoundingBox, 4326)
    SELECT PostalCode, geography::STGeomFromText(geometry::STGeomFromText(geo.AsTextZM(),4326).STIntersection(@BoundingBoxGeo).AsTextZM(),4326) AS geo
    FROM [geo].[AustralianGeoData]   
    WHERE  zoom=@Zoom AND geometry::STGeomFromText(geo.AsTextZM(),4326).STIntersects(@BoundingBoxGeo)=1
    AND geo.STGeometryType() IN ('Polygon','MultiPolygon','GeometryCollection')
END
```